# Passport.js not matching password

Tags: javascript, html, nodejs, passport

Hola estoy usando **Passporrt.js** para validar contraseñas , pero por alguna razon no las estoy podiendo machear, alguien sabe porque ? o podria decirme mi error si lo notan?

```
passport.use('local.signin', new LStrategy({
    usernameField: 'email',
    passwordField: 'password',
    passReqToCallback: true
}, async (req, email, passwordSend, done) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    console.log(email, passwordSend);

    const qu = pool.query('SELECT * FROM  users where email = ?',[email]);
    qu.then( async (res) => {

        if (res.length > 0) {
            const user = res[0];
            console.log(user);
            const validpass = await helpers.matchPass(passwordSend, user.password);
            console.log("VALID PASSWORD = " + validpass );
            if (validpass) {
                done(null,user,req.flash('success','Bienvenido '));
            }else{
                done(null,false,req.flash('message','Contraseña invalida'));
            }

        }else {
            done(null,false,req.flash('message','Usuario invalido '));
        }
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
}));
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<form action="/signin" method="POST">
  <fieldset>  
    <div class="form-group row top2" align="center">
       <h3>Todo for image</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label mt-4">Email address</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
      <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="form-label mt-4">Password</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
   
   <br/>   
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

```
helpers.matchPass = async (pass, savedPass) => {
    try{
        console.log(pass,savedPass)
        return await bcrypt.compare(pass, savedPass);
    }catch(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
};
```

Comment: Puede que estés introduciendo mal la contraseña, una pregunta ¿Cómo encriptas la contraseña, puedes mostrar la función?

Answer (score 1):

El problema que yo veo es que el hash $2a$10$0zDLXxVbg2YGCd7mPNRF/.wXyZIxNPWPyI9YTd no corresponde a la cadena '12345678', comparando con `console.log( bcrypt.compareSync('12345678', '$2a$10$0zDLXxVbg2YGCd7mPNRF/.wXyZIxNPWPyI9YTd') );`.

Te sugiero rehacer los hashes en tu base de datos (actualizarlos) con la función `bcrypt.hashSync('12345678',n)` n:rondas de sal, para asegurarte como fueron generados tus hashes de contraseñas.
Para mayor referencia la documentación de bcrypt https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt

Aquí mi ejemplo completo:

```
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const hash=bcrypt.hashSync('12345678',2);

console.log(hash);
console.log( bcrypt.compareSync('12345678', '$2a$10$0zDLXxVbg2YGCd7mPNRF/.wXyZIxNPWPyI9YTd') );
console.log( bcrypt.compareSync('12345678', hash) );
```